# Java - class name starts with numbers

Tags: java, class-names

I have done my HW already but our instructor wants us to submit our HWs as yourID_BFS_DFS.java. And I can't do that, it returns error. **I know** that numbers are not Java letters and **it is illegal** (I checked other answers already) but still I want to ask you guys if there is a way (maybe a trick) to do that or he simply wants us to accomplish something illegal? And if I am not wrong, java language is updated recent days, and maybe it is about that, I don't know really.

B.t.w. I can't reach him to ask, he never replies. That's why I am asking here again.

Comment: Java class names cannot start with numbers. Maybe he wants an alphabetic ID? Not sure what "ID" precisely means at your educational institution.

Comment: Maybe he just wants you to rename the file before submitting it, then he will remove the prefix before compiling it.

Comment: Just a bit dfferent, you can try submit as `class Three1120298466_BFS_DFS`.

Comment: It's not a good way to do it, but you could start with an underscore.

Comment: Ask your instructor aboud this. If they don't provide details, just use `_` as prefix befor your id, it's a common practice.

Comment: @Downvoter What exactly is the problem with this question? Seems perfectly valid for me.

Comment: @egazi not to detract from your feelings but "everyone" is three people, against 5 that actually gave you advice :)

Comment: use underscore _!

Comment: I agree with all of you but I think he has some kind of script file to evaluate everyone's HWs, and he especially wrote down that to the handout: "Save your file as yourID_ BFS_DFS.java and upload only yourID_ BFS_DFS.java file"

Comment: @lexicore An image of code often attracts down votes.

Comment: Sounds like your instructor likes to write code with notepad. I'd use a proper class name, then just for submission rename the file using a filemanager, not touching the class name.

Comment: @Ivar Image usage is OK in this case - it shows the error the OP get in the IDE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first character needs to be a "Java letter", which includes letters, underscore and dollar sign.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8

> An identifier is an unlimited-length sequence of Java letters and Java
>   digits, the first of which must be a Java letter.
>   [...]
>
> The "Java letters" include uppercase and lowercase ASCII Latin letters
>   A-Z (\u0041-\u005a), and a-z (\u0061-\u007a), and, for historical
>   reasons, the ASCII underscore (_, or \u005f) and dollar sign ($, or
>   \u0024). The $ character should be used only in mechanically generated
>   source code or, rarely, to access pre-existing names on legacy
>   systems.
>   [...]
>
> Letters and digits may be drawn from the entire Unicode character set,
>   which supports most writing scripts in use in the world today,
>   including the large sets for Chinese, Japanese, and Korean. This
>   allows programmers to use identifiers in their programs that are
>   written in their native languages.

Comment: "Java letter" is a bit broader than "letter".

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Fair enough, I included the relevant parts about what is a "Java Letter".

Comment: I am just going to accept this answer and wait for the reply from the instructor. He is in silence since yesterday, and I think I don't have any other chance to wait for him. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Not possible to begin java class with number.
I guess he means you should do it in this format "IDxxxxxx_BFS_DFS"

But the best way to understand is ask him for clarifications.

Comment: I asked via mail, but he is in silence :))